# Issue with the controller of a UI Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular. I have created a component with a template (panel.html) and a controller (allPanelsRetrieved). When a specific button defined in the template is clicked, the showDetails() function specified in the controller is called. This function triggers the opening of a modal dialog specified by a template (panel-list.details-template.html) and a controller, which are both defined inside the allPanelsRetrieved controller. The problem is that the modal dialog is displayed but the controller doesn't work (the click of the OK button does nothing). Where the problem may be? Thanks in advance

```
angular.
module('panelList')
.component('panelList', {
  templateUrl: '/panel-list/panel.html',
  controller: ['Panel', 'NgTableParams','$scope', '$location', '$uibModal',
   function PanelListController(Panel, NgTableParams, $scope, $location, $uibModal) {

  this.allPanelsRetrieved = (index, before) => {
  //..hidden code here  
  }

  this.showDetails = function () {
    $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: '/panel-list/panel-list.details-template.html',
      controller: function ($uibModalInstance) {
        let $ctrl = this;
        $ctrl.ok = function () {
          $uibModalInstance.close();
        };
      },
    }).result.then(
      function (success) {
        alert(success);
      },
      function (error) {
        alert(error);
      }
    );
  };
 }]
});
```

Here is the template panel-list.details-template.html:

```
<div>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/panel-list/panel-list.details-template.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title">Modal title</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            Modal content
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$ctrl.ok()">Close</button>
        </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please add the code of `panel-list.details-template.html` ?

Comment: I have just added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$scope` to make it work in the AngularJS way. Here is a [working plnkr demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/c3fNSbBV8TnyhKHuTpTt?p=preview) of what you try to achieve.

```
$uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: '/panel-list/panel-list.details-template.html',
    controller: function ($uibModalInstance, $scope) {
        $scope.ok = function () {
            $uibModalInstance.close();
        };
    }
}).result.then(
    function (success) {
        alert(success);
    },
    function (error) {
        alert(error);
    }
);
```

#### View

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/panel-list/panel-list.details-template.html">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Modal title</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    Modal content
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">Close</button>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: this is a dirty work around, the problem is not about using scope or not

Comment: @Yaser Added a working example, what exactly is a "dirty work arround"?

Comment: I didn't say it doesn't work, it is just ignoring the issue and using scope to solve it instead of understanding why it doesn't work as is

Comment: @Yaser Well m8, you need to understand the E2E binding in AngularJS. `$ctrl` isnt available in your VIEW because its not binded by two way databinding. So, `ng-click="$ctrl.ok()"` will never been executed. Thats why we use `$scope` in AngularJS which is the clean way to handle E2E bindings in AngularJS. It is not "dirty" as you suggest.

Comment: I am wasting my time here, why do you think they removed the scope from angular2 and even before that they added the components and controllerAs?

Comment: @Anto  yeah i know =)

Answer (score 0):

While the `angular.component` implementation provides a default for the `controllerAs` syntax...

```
controllerAs: identifierForController(options.controller) || options.controllerAs || '$ctrl',
```

...it appears that angular-ui-bootstrap does not.

Simply provide a value for `controllerAs` in your $uibModal options to continue using the preferred syntax.

```
$uibModal.open({
  templateUrl: '/panel-list/panel-list.details-template.html',
  controllerAs: '$ctrl',
  controller: function($uibModalInstance) {
    let $ctrl = this;
    $ctrl.ok = function () {
      $uibModalInstance.close();
    }
  }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/q1arN18553XoUZEuPcPl?p=preview

Answer (score -2):

The problem is with this keyword as you are using it. Use arrow function instead and it will work:

```
$uibModal.open({
  templateUrl: '/panel-list/panel-list.details-template.html',
  controller: ($uibModalInstance) => {
    let $ctrl = this;
    $ctrl.ok = function () {
      $uibModalInstance.close();
    };
  },
})
```

Comment: Hi Yaser, unfortunately doesn't work. Thanks for you help anyway

Comment: have you set controllerAs in the modal itself? @Anto and what error are getting

Comment: I am not getting any error. Clicking the Close button just doesn't do anything

Comment: I will create a plunker for you, just give a couple of mins

Comment: Hi Yaser, Lin's code works. Thanks for you help and support!

Comment: A controller can't be an arrow.